# function "converges" to prime counting function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, graphing-functions, approximation

Consider $f(x)=\ln(\pi(e^x))$ (blue) and $g(x)=\ln(li(e^x))$ (green). $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function and $li(x)$ the logarithmic integral. I plotted these on SageCell and what surprised me is that the differences of $f$ and $g$ seem to tend to zero (at least in this interval) (red):

[image]

What am I missing here?

> Is $g$ really that good of an approximation to this prime counting function $f$?

Comment: $\text{li}(x)$ is a good approximation of $\pi(x)$. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#More_precise_estimates)

Comment: @StevenClark does li(x) converge to pi(x)?

Comment: What I'm talking about is images of li(x) and pi(x) given by g and f respectively. Clearly li(x) is only asympotic to the prime counting function and the differences increase quite quickly for larger x. Now f and g have a much stronger property in that the differences tend to zero as x goes to infinity.

Comment: See the link in my comment above for the relationship between $\text{li}(x)$ and $\pi(x)$, but $\pi(x)−li(x)$ is known to change sign infinitely many times.

Comment: @StevenClark But $\lim_{x \to \infty} |\pi(x) -li(x)|$ does not tend to zero

Comment: Compare that with $\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x)-g(x)|$ which tends to zero. Which would you say is a better approximation?

Comment: I didn't say it did, but the link provides a bound on the difference which can perhaps be used to prove a bound on the difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Plotting over such a limited range can be very misleading. The first time $\pi(x)−li(x)$ changes sign is near $x=1.397\times 10^{316}$ (see [Skewes's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number))

Comment: The reason this seems better is the, somewhat artificial, logarithm. Note $\lim_{x\to\infty}|\ln(\pi(e^x))-\ln(li(e^x))| = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left|\ln\left(\frac{\pi(e^x)}{li(e^x)}\right)\right|=|\ln(1)|=0$.

Comment: @Mastrem so it's not actually better?

Comment: No, $\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x)-g(x)|=0$ is equivalent to the PNT.